# prevent ajax request caching in IE during post method

Tags: ajax, caching, request

How to prevent IE from caching the request sent to the server?

i tried by setting ("Cache-Control: no-cache) in the https response object but still the IE is caching my request data.

Please find tmy project details as below:

in my application i am sending login request to the server. so after i login if i take the memory dump using winHex tool i am able to get the password details in the memory.

1. i am clearing the dialog refrense also but still the request data is getting cached.

Please suggest me some work arround for this

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add a parameter to your URL with a random value, this will prevent that the URL is always thesame.

Example:

*Normal URL:*

```
www.test.com/test.php
```

*Fake different URL:*

```
www.test.com/test.php?_dc=12353somerandomval
```

Make sure the `_dc` parameter always has a different value, you can (for example) use JavaScript date object for this (It returns the current time in milliseconds, which will virtually always be different):

```
params: {
    _dc : new Date().getTime()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a project I did a while back I had the exact same issues, I searched around and saw a few things that recommended adding a time stamp to the request, that does work too, but this was the most elegant way that worked for me.

```
$('document').ready(function () {            
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you we just implemented RSA encryption for the data send by the web client to server. We tried with time stamp option also but didnt worked